# MySQL join two tables and retun data from both tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a pretty simple MySQL query, that joins two tables:

```
SELECT teams.id, teams.name, players.id, players.name, players.teamId
FROM teams
LEFT JOIN players
ON teams.id = players.zoneId
WHERE teamId = 3
```

When I then fetch the rows, I can use the data like this:

```
echo($row["name"] . ", " . $row["id"]);
```

The data contained in the array, is the data from the players table. How can I also access the data from the "teams" table ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use aliases for column names to differentiate between columns from team table and players table that have same names.

```
SELECT teams.id as team_id, teams.name as team_name, players.id, players.name, players.teamId
FROM teams
LEFT JOIN players
ON teams.id = players.zoneId
WHERE teamId = 3
```

Then you can use the below to get team name and team id:

```
$row["team_name"]
$row["team_id"]
```

If it were me, I'd also use aliases for the player fields (e.g. player_id, etc.) just to make the code as clear as possible. Clear code == better maintainability.